Firebase code is not loading model from storage
The code is calling file from firebase cloud storage and using that file to do stuff like image detection which is intended with model, but the function which was deployed using this code is giving an error. Even loading the model api is giving an error. If I use the model URL directly in web, it returns

"code": 412, "message": "A required service account is missing
necessary permissions. Please resolve by visiting the Storage page of
the Firebase Console and re-linking your Firebase bucket or see this
FAQ for more info:
https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts. If you
recently made changes to your service account, please wait a few
minutes for the changes to propagate through our systems and try
again.""

const admin = require(`firebase-admin`);
const functions = require(`firebase-functions`);
const express = require(`express`);
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require("canvas");
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const sharp = require('sharp');
const jimp = require('jimp');
admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();
const main = express();
app.use(cors);
main.use(`/api/v1`, app);
main.use(express.json());
main.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));

// Load the TensorFlow.js model
const MODEL_URL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ambrosadetection-xxxxx/o/model.json?alt=media&token=7065043a-294a-4f4b-b641-b682c0e04fad&_gl=1*n8n5vk*_ga*MjA1MjgyMTM2MS4xNjc5ODI5MzMx*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjAwNDQ5NS4yNS4xLjE2ODxxxxxxx.";
let modelPromise = null;

async function loadModel() {
  if (modelPromise) {
    return modelPromise;
  }
  modelPromise = tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);
  return modelPromise;
}

And I am unable to find this relinking anywhere. I have admin permissions in google cloud and many things in firebase, yet i couldn't find this relinking.
